# mesh is cutted in unity (grass made of plans)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, game-development, modeling

[First side of the grass (i think the front)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtBEl.jpg)
[Second side of the grass (back ??) ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHiwR.jpg)

So my grass is made by two plans and i think the issue is cause by the faces of my mesh, do anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?

i have tried to duplicate and rotate the faces, activate all options XD